# java animation, making an object change color every 'x' seconds

Tags: java, swing, flash, animation, timer

hi there i was just wondering if someone could help me or give me some advice with timers, the problem i have got is that i need an object to change color every x seconds on click of a button 'flash' and stay a single color on click of a button 'steady' so far i have got my buttons to work i just cant seem to get the object to 'flash'(change color on its own). my code is below and works without problems.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


/**
 * Created by joe on 26/03/15.
 */

    class Beacon extends JPanel {
    private boolean lightOn = true;

    private int x = 150;
    private int y = 90;
    private int ballSize = 55;

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
                if (lightOn){
                    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    g2.fillRect(172, 140, 12, 30);
                    g2.drawRect(172, 170, 11, 30);
                    g2.fillRect(172, 200, 12, 30);
                    g2.drawRect(172, 230, 11, 30);
                    g2.fillRect(172, 260, 12, 30);
                    g2.drawRect(172, 290, 11, 30);
                    g2.fillRect(172, 320, 12, 30);
                    g2.drawRect(172, 350, 11, 30);
                    g2.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
                    g2.fillOval(x, y, ballSize, ballSize);
                }
            else{
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.fillRect(172, 140, 12, 30);
        g2.drawRect(172, 170, 11, 30);
        g2.fillRect(172, 200, 12, 30);
        g2.drawRect(172, 230, 11, 30);
        g2.fillRect(172, 260, 12, 30);
        g2.drawRect(172, 290, 11, 30);
        g2.fillRect(172, 320, 12, 30);
        g2.drawRect(172, 350, 11, 30);
        g2.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g2.fillOval(x, y, ballSize, ballSize);
    }   }
    public void lightOn() { lightOn = true; }
    public void lightOff() { lightOn = false; }
}

    public class BeaconViewer extends JFrame
    {
        JButton Flash = new JButton("Flash");
        JButton Steady = new JButton("Steady");
        JPanel bPanel = new JPanel();
        Beacon bbPanel = new Beacon();



    public BeaconViewer()
    {
        bPanel.add(Flash);
        this.add(bPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        bPanel.add(Steady);
        this.add(bbPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        Flash.addActionListener(new FlashListener());
        Steady.addActionListener(new SteadyListener());
    }

        class FlashListener implements ActionListener {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                bbPanel.lightOff();
                repaint();

            }

        }

        class SteadyListener implements ActionListener {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
                bbPanel.lightOn();
                repaint();
            }

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame scFrame = new BeaconViewer();
        scFrame.setTitle("Belish Beacon");
        scFrame.setSize(300, 500);
        scFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation((JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE));
        scFrame.setVisible(true); }}
```

Comment: Don't create two methods (lightOn() and lightOff). Normally to manage a property in your class you would have a "getter" and a "setter" method. So in your case, since you called your variable name is `lightOn`, I would suggest you create two methods `isLightOn()` and `setLightOn(boolean lightOn)`. Then in the `setLightOn(...)` method you would invoke `repaint()` so the new state of your property can be reflected on the GUI.

Answer (score 2):

What you'd like to do is use a swing timer and register it an `AbstractAction` or `ActionListener` which it will fire based on a delay parameter that you pass it.

For example, I may have...

```
...
Timer timer = new Timer(FRAME_DELAY, myActionListener);
timer.start();
...
```

where `FRAME_DELAY` is the number of milliseconds between event firings and `myActionListener` receives the notification of the action performed.

Once you have the timer you can adjust the delay, stop, and restart among other things. See [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) for better information.

Answer (score 2):

Start by taking a look at [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

First you need someway to tell if the `Beacon` is on or off, we achieve this by adding

```
public boolean isLighOff() {
    return !lightOn;
}
```

to the `Beacon` class.

Next, we need an instance of `javax.swing.Timer`

```
public class BeaconViewer extends JFrame {
    //...
    private Timer flashTimer;

    public BeaconViewer() {
        //...
        flashTimer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (bbPanel.isLighOff()) {
                    bbPanel.lightOn();
                } else {
                    bbPanel.lightOff();
                }
                repaint();
            }
        });
        flashTimer.setInitialDelay(0);
    }
```

This is used to schedule a regular call back at the specified duration (1 second) which determines the current state of the `Beacon` and switches the state...The reason for using a Swing `Timer` like this, apart from simplicity, is because it's safe to modify the UI components from within the assigned `ActionListener`

Next, we need to start and top the `Timer` accordingly...

```
class FlashListener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        flashTimer.start();
    }

}

class SteadyListener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        if (flashTimer.isRunning()) {
            flashTimer.stop();
        }
        bbPanel.lightOn();
        repaint();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy to accomplish, all you need to do is use `System.currentTimeMillis()` something like this

```
start = System.currentTimeMillis()
//stuff
finish = System.currentTimeMillis()
elapsed = finish - start
```

if the result is greater than 1,000 then a second has passed. You will probably want to put this timer in a separate thread depending on how you want to implement it in your program.